# Angular datatable length menu not set data at the time of length menu change at server side

Tags: angularjs, angular-datatables

By default, length menu is set to 10 at the time of loading. After that I am going on 4th page at that time display records are from 31 to 40 and after that I am changing length menu to 25 then it is display data from 31 to 55 rather display this result, it will actually display record from 25 to 50 and 2nd Page.

This functionality is working in jquery datatable but not working in angular datatable.

Here is my code.

```
    vm.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions()
            .withOption('ajax',
                    {
                        // Either you specify the AjaxDataProp here
                        url: CATEGORY_URL + 'processCategory/1',
                        type: 'POST',
                        complete: function (response)
                        {
                            if (response.responseJSON !== undefined && response.responseJSON.FLAG == 2)
                            {
                                callSessionOutDialog();
                            }

                            if (response.responseJSON !== undefined && response.responseJSON.FLAG == 3)
                            {
                                growl.addErrorMessage(response.responseJSON.MSG);
                            }
                        }
                    })
            // or here
            .withDataProp('data')
            .withOption('processing', true)
            .withOption('serverSide', true)
            .withOption('lengthMenu', [[10, 20, 50], [10, 20, 50]])
            .withPaginationType('full_numbers')
            .withOption('createdRow', createdRow);
    vm.dtColumns = [
        DTColumnBuilder.newColumn("in_category_id").withTitle("Category ID").notVisible(),
        DTColumnBuilder.newColumn("st_category_title").withTitle("Category Name").withOption('searchable', true),
        DTColumnBuilder.newColumn(null).withTitle("Category Type").notSortable().renderWith(categoryType).withOption('sWidth', "15%"),
        DTColumnBuilder.newColumn(null).withTitle("Actions").notSortable().renderWith(actionHtml).withOption('sWidth', '14%')
    ];
```

Please help me to solve this.

Thanks.